# Bootstrap modal won't close

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

That's what I put together so far:
http://jsfiddle.net/1geq21c9/

If I remove the `return false;` in line 5 and try to add a new user I get an error from JSFiddle. Opening exactly the same thing from my browser I can briefly see the new table row, then the modal closes and the row is gone again.

With the `return false;` statement everything works fine except that the modal won't close anymore (programmatically). It still can be closed by hand.

I already tried a few approaches of closing the modal which didn't improve anything.

Another issue I encountered was that I never got any of the modal events. I tried this piece of code and nothing happened:

```
$("#addUserModal").on("hidden.bs.modal", function () { ... });
```

Any kind of help or hints would be greatly appreciated, mostly for the modal not closing/row disappearing thing since I managed to work around the missing modal events already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't tell why your code won't work...
But if you're okay with this,

```
$('.modal').modal('hide');
```

instead of

```
$('#addUserModal').modal('hide');
```

will do the trick.

EDIT

You have a spelling issue.

```
addUserModal instead of addUserMod**e**l
```